# Inserir Imagem pelo CSS ou pelo HTML?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, imagem

Olá! Estou com uma duvida sobre a diferença nas formas de inserir imagens.

Sei que posso inserir imagens pelo **HTML** e pelo **CSS**.
Mas  qual a diferença? E em qual situação devo usar cada um deles da maneira correta ?

Answer (score 3):

De forma grosseira. Quando você coloca a imagem direto no **HTML** ela é de certa forma "registrada" em buscadores, como no Google, então usuários podem te encontrar pelo Google Imagens, além de ser mais fácil de seus usuários baixarem suas imagens (Botão direito do Mouse > Salvar Imagem Como, isso no Windows, por exemplo). Com o **CSS** ela não é "registrada" nos buscadores e é um pouco mais difícil de seu usuários baixar a imagem.

Tem o fato da acessibilidade, que com o HTML você pode proporcionar aos seus usuários, desconheço uma forma de fazer isso com CSS.

Comment: obrigado!  já me ajudou muito.
tô com uma imagem para inserir no header do meu site .
tava na duvida se usava pelo CSS ou pelo HTML.
acredito que pelo  HTML é o ideal né ?

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado :D. Acredito que sim, normalmente no header se coloca logo ou alguma imagem importante do produto, então é igual eu falei, isso pode te ajudar a ranquear no Google Imagens ou para facilitar seu próprio usuário baixar.

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade a forma que colocou em sua pergunta está da maneira errada, o correto seria:

- No HTML

```html
<img src="exemplo.jpg" />
```

Acima é como se insere uma imagem na página HTML por meio da *tag* **img**

- No CSS

```css
body {
  background-image: url("exemplo.jpg");
}
```

Já nessa segunda forma, está colocando uma imagem não como elemento na página, mas sim como imagem de fundo de algum elemento da página.

Comment: acredito que você entendeu a pergunta.